# Semisimple Lie groups with finite center

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras

Before the problem, here goes the background: let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Consider $X_s$ an semisimple element of $\mathfrak{g}$ such that every eigenvalue of  $e^{ad(X_s)}$ has norm $1$. By 'semisimple element' we understand that to the complexification $\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$, the operator $\hbox{ad}X_s$ is conjugated to a diagonal matrix.

Now, consider the set
\begin{equation} 
K_0 = \hbox{cl}\{\exp{(tX_s)}: t \in \mathbb{R}\}. 
\end{equation}

If $G = KAN$ is the Iwasawa decomposition of the Lie group $G$, by theorem 7.2, pg. 431 of   Helgason's book - *Differential Geometry, Lie groups and symmetric spaces* - the element $e^{ad(X_s)}$ is conjugated to an element of $K$.

**My problem is:** considering that $G$ has finite center, I'm trying to prove that $K_0$ is compact using the fact that $K$ is compact, but I have no clue about how to do it. I've tried to use open covers, unsuccessfully.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what your difficulty is.
The group $K_0$ is abelian connected and locally compact. The set of its compact elements is dense. It follows that $K_0$ is compact. Isn't it?
Recall that an element $g$ of a topological group is compact if $g$ lies in a compact subgroup.

Comment: I really didn't know the concept of compact elements. Can you give me some reference about it? Also, you said "The set of its compact elements is dense". I would like to see the argument behind this result, can you give a reference for that? Thank you.

Comment: For a  survey on compact elements of connected Lie groups, see [here](https://www.heldermann.de/JLT/JLT27/JLT272/jlt27030.htm).
But your case is much simpler. If I may give a detailed answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First recall that an element $g$ of a topological group $G$ is called compact if $g$ is contained in a compact subgroup of $G$.
Now let's use the formula ($x=X_s\in\mathfrak{g}$)
$$
\operatorname{Ad}(\exp x) = \exp(\operatorname{ad}x)
\text{ as operators }\ \mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{g}
$$
If every eigenvalue of $\exp(\operatorname{ad}x)$ has norm $1$ and
$\operatorname{ad}x$ is a semi-simple operator on $\mathfrak{g}$,
then $\operatorname{Ad}(\exp x)$ is a compact element in $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$.
Since $G$ is a semi-simple group and $G$ has finite center, it follows that
$\exp x$ is a compact element in $G$.

Let $L=\{\exp tx\mid t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.
The group $L$ is a one-parameter subgroup of the Lie group $G$.
Therefore, by virtue of Exercise C.2 on page 150 of Helgason's book,
the subgroup $L$ is either closed or has compact closure.
If $L$ is closed and non-compact, then $L\cong\mathbb{R}$ and
$L$ has no nontrivial compact elements. This contradicts the fact that $\exp x$ is a compact element.

Consequently $K_0=\operatorname{cl}(L)$ is a compact group.

---

More detailed answer to the question "Why is $\exp x$ a compact element of $G$ if $\operatorname{Ad}(\exp x)$ is a compact element of $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$?"

1. We know that $\operatorname{Ad}:G\to\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ is a Lie group homomorphism.
2. Since $G$ is a semisimple connected Lie group, $\operatorname{Ker}(\operatorname{Ad})$ is a discrete subgroup coinciding with the center $Z(G)$ of $G$.
3. Let $\operatorname{Ad}(\exp x)\in A$, where $A$ is a compact subgroup of the group $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$.
4. Since the $Z(G)$ is finite, the preimage $B=\operatorname{Ad}^{-1}(A)$ is a compact subgroup of $G$.
5. We have $\exp x\in B$. Hence $\exp x$ is a compact element of group $G$.

Comment: Everything seems correct to me, thank you. You are only using intrisic properties of $K_0$, is that right? Does not the fact of $G$ having finite center add anything to the proof? I was trying to use this and the fact of every element of $K_0$ is conjugated to some element of $K$ (which is compact iff $Z(G)$ is finite), given the Iwasawa decomposition above.

Comment: Also, in the part "Since the set of compact elements of $K_0$ is dense in $K_0$, it follows that $n=0$ and $K_0$ is compact". Why is $n=0$?

Comment: "Why is n=0? " On the one hand, the set of compact elements is dense in $K_0$; on the other hand, the set of compact elements forms a compact subgroup $C$ closed in $K_0$. Therefore, $K_0=C$.  I repeat, it seems to me that the assumptions on center and  semi-simplicity are not needed.

Comment: Thank you. The argument is very clear. This concept of compact element is new to me. I think I will study this better later.

Comment: Why "L consists of compact elements"? which compact subgroup does the element $e^{tX_s}$ belongs to? the first structure theorem claims that $K_0$ is topologically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n \times C$, here $C$ is a LCA group which contains a open compact subgroup.

Comment: It seems like the goalposts have moved since I answered. Tricky to keep up with changing questions! I have edited my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry about the changes. The article I'm reading states that this is an easy fact to verify, so I didn't expect such a complicated answer, which is why I was so interested in compact elements. This is (I believe) the last loose end of my dissertation. Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: You're welcome. @Tmath, I am very sorry that I could not find a simpler answer to your question. My best wishes for the successful completion of your dissertation. Good luck in everything.

Comment: Just one last thing (if you don't mind): you put "Since $G$ is a semisimple group and $G$ has a finite center, it follows that $exp x$ is a compact element in $G$" . I didn't get it that easy. Can you elaborate or give me some hints? It seems very simple, but I'm struggling to understand this statement.

Comment: Tmath, I don't mind. I've added more details to my answer. It's certainly simple, but a little long. If you still have any questions, I'd be happy to answer them for you.

Comment: One last thing (I promise): considering $\alpha$ an eigenvalue of $Ad(e^X)$ (which has norm $1$) with eigenspace $E_{\alpha}$, I believe that the set $A$ is the group of all isometries of $E_{ \alpha}$, right? The set $A$ is certainly compact (by corollary 1.2 of http://www.numdam.org/item/RSMUP_2006__116__187_0.pdf).  Furthermore, is the set $B = Ad^{-1}(A)$ contained in $K$? If it is true, why? If $B \subset K$, $B$ is compact since $A$ is closed and $K$ is compact ($Z(G)$ is finite).

Comment: If $A=\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{Ad}(\exp x))$, then apparently the answer is yes. Only we remember that if $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue with norm 1, then generally speaking $\alpha$ is a complex number. Therefore, $E_\alpha\subset\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{C}$.

To the second part of your question. It seems to me that it is unlikely to expect that $B$ lies in $K$. It is possible that it is conjugate to a subgroup of $K$.

Comment: Ok. Why does the finiteness of $Z(G)$ imply that $B$ is compact?

Comment: @Tmath This is a well-known fact:
Let $G$ be a topological group.
If a normal subgroup $N$ and the factor group $G/N$ are
both compact, then $G$ itself is compact.
See L. Pontrjagin "Topological Groups", 1946, page 61.
If you don't have a chance to look at this book, there is a similar statement in Hewitt and Ross' book Abstract Harmonic Analysis (Theorem 5.25).

Comment: I really appreciate all the effort you made to answer me @kabenyuk. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad to have helped you!